# API call using Pest PHP class returns results with error

Tags: php, api, rest

I'm doing what I would consider to be the most basic API call to the web-app at http://rolz.org/api/?4d20 using [Pest PHP REST client](https://github.com/educoder/pest/blob/master/Pest.php). Using a Chrome plugin REST client, I get the expected results without an error:

```
result=45
details= [ 16 +20 +3 +6  ] 
code=4d20
illustration=<span class="dc_dice_a">4</span><span class="dc_dice_d">D20</span>
timestamp=1370200094
```

However, using Pest PHP REST client, my results are prepended with an error message:

```
string $rolldice = result=Error: please check your formula (/52)

details=/ [ 9 +16 +20 +7  ] 
code=/4d20
illustration=<span class="dc_operator">/</span><span class="dc_dice_a">4</span><span class="dc_dice_d">D20</span>
timestamp=1370200381
```

using this code:

```
include '../Pest.php';

function callDieRoller($num, $faces){
    $result = array();
    $curl = curl_init();

    $url = 'http://rolz.org/api/?';
    $pest = new Pest($url);

    $rolldice = $pest->get($num.'d'.$faces);
    $results = $rolldice;

    return $results;

}
```

Why am I getting errors when making the API call with Pest?

Comment: Why do you need the `curl` code?

Comment: I suppose these were carry-overs from a pre-Pest implementation. Removed, and still get the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `Pest` ensures `/` between base api url and called url, so you are calling something like `http://rolz.org/api/?/4d20`. To make it work properly, you must define base url without question mark, and add it in front of every call:

```
$url = 'http://rolz.org/api/';
$pest = new Pest($url);

$rolldice = $pest->get('?'.$num.'d'.$faces);
$results = $rolldice;
```

Comment: Yup, that did it! Thanks!
`function callDieRoller($num, $faces){

    $url = 'http://rolz.org/api';
    $pest = new Pest($url);
    
    $rolldice = $pest->get('?'.$num.'d'.$faces);
    
    $results = $rolldice;
    return $results;
}
`